# React Native: What prevents a TouchableOpacity from being able to be clicked right away?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, freeze, touchableopacity

I have a `<TouchableOpacity>` in my React Native app, and some users have noticed that if they click it right when the screen loads, it does nothing, but if they wait 10 or 15 seconds, they can click it. There are a bunch of pieces of data that are being fetched after the screen loads, so I can't share all the code that gets run on this screen, but what I want to know is how to approach this. What are the general things that could cause a `<TouchableOpacity>` to not be clickable for a few seconds? What kind of thing should I be looking for, like asynchronous API calls?

Comment: if something is getting focus... focus needs to be clear before TouchableOpacity is interactable. that's a weird thing to check for.

Comment: Could you give me an example?